# How to format USB Drive using Python?

Tags: python

> How can I implement a feature or function that formats a USB Flash drive using Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format a USB drive to FAT32 using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45198280/format-a-usb-drive-to-fat32-using-python)

Comment: To be on-topic here you need to ask about a specific place where you got stuck while trying to solve this yourself. Showing your work (in enough detail to describe a specific problem, without going over the minimum necessary to let us reproduce the issue -- see [mre] guidelines for more) will incidentally give us important details, like which operating system you're on -- an answer for Linux, an answer for Windows, and an answer for MacOS will all be different from each other.